# MS SQL Server Cores / License To Purchase

Tags: sql-server, sql

After almost 6 years I'm approaching the 10 GB limit of my MS SQLExpress deployment. I'm looking at the licensing for MS-SQLServer and am getting more confused with everything I read.  Can anyone help set the "**Standard - server + CAL**" vs "**Standard - per core**" licensing concepts straight in my head?

The application we use uses one user with about 12 sessions as per:

[image]

The Hardware has this profile:

[image]

So am I looking at one "**Standard - server + CAL**" for $1,000 based on the application usage or a "**Standard - per core**" based on the number of hardware cores?  Or have I twisted my brain around this so much that I'm lost?

Comment: Sorry about the VTC, but the only possible answer to software licensing questions is "you should really ask the vendor".

Comment: I suppose that is wise but contacting MS has resulted in them suggesting I contact a reseller (store) about 50 miles away who does not want to talk over the phone.  But the point is well taken.  I'm more interested in understanding than having someone telling me what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1):

This is a RTFM question - it is not like the licensing documents are secret.

Generally:

Server + CAL means:

- You need a server license AND every user needs a CAL (CLient Access License). The details vary, per product and version, but this is general gist.
- Per Core means this. You need to license Cores. This is gnerally WAY more expensive than Server + CAL... but you do not need the CAL anymore.

In case of LIMITED KNOWN USERS (i.e. one user) it is GENERALLY better to go Server + CAL. In case of a LOT of users, it MAY be better to go per core as you do not need a CAL then.

Again, grab the specific documents AND READ THEM.

Comment: Also, the definition of "users" may vary a lot; almost nobody directly uses a database, but if you use a software which uses the database as a back-end, users of the software *might* be considered database users. That's where most of the confusion ensues.